# How to replace values in one dataframe with values from another dataframe using index in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have to dataframes, which is called node_list and sup. Node_list consists of ID and loca2, which looks lile

| ID | loca2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

and sup looks like

| ID | To |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

and I wish to replace the ID and to in sup by loca2 in node_list, which looks like

| ID | To |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | A |
| C | A |

how should i make it by R?
thanks a lot!!! :)

to be honest i have no idea how to achieve this and chatgpt is horrible on this so i'm left with no choice!

Comment: Are the first two data.frames always the same length and in the same ID order? Or does a proper merge need to happen?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/73979705/680068

Comment: NO they are not of the same length, and chatgpt generate answer using merge by will cause the problem of unmatched rows of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to make `node_list$loca2` into a named vector and call this as a replacement for each column:

```r
library(tidyverse)

node_list <- tibble(ID = 1:3,
       loca2 = LETTERS[1:3])

names(node_list$loca2) <- node_list$ID

sup <- tibble(ID = 1:3, To = c(2, 1, 1))

sup |> 
  mutate(ID = node_list$loca2[as.character(ID)],
         To = node_list$loca2[as.character(To)])
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   ID    To   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A     B    
#> 2 B     A    
#> 3 C     A
```